# Ставится ли запятая после слова "сегодня"?

Tags: запятые

Сегодня каким способом будете погашать?

Answer (score 1):

Никаких причин для постановки запятой нет. Неправильно думать, что перед словами *какой, как, что, где и др.* всегда нужна запятая. Произносится ровно, без паузы, что тоже говорит не в пользу запятой.